# Icon Editor for Android platform

Tags: applications, photos, graphics

I was looking for an app that would let me create and edit icons on my Android device. It actually doesn't need to be able to open .ICO files or anything like that, but rather normal image files like jpeg, png, or gif. There are a lot of normal photo editors available, but none of them are well suited to creating icons. I would like to be able to place the individual pixels, like when using the draw tool in gimp or PS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, How about Photoshop Touch? Might be a tad expensive for your needs, but it is essentially a toned-down, mobile edition of the Adobe product.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.adobe.pstouch

Of course, if you really want it but can't fork out the dough, there's always downloading the apk (but you didn't hear it from me, developers don't worry I support you guys :P ).

If you're looking to create icons to use as replacements right on your device, and are inclined to a minimalistic style, then Simple Text is a good way to go.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redphx.simpletext

Comment: PS: I know that you wanted to stick to your Android device, but for what it's worth, Google provides an icon generator here: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=ffffff%2C100 .

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do recall having ps touch on a previous device but I never really used it, and was not aware of the extent of it's functionality. Anyhow, that's what I'm using now. Kudos.